# how do I change default emacs format for `{}`

Tags: emacs

The default format when I write a `while` statement is as follows:

```
  while(true)
    {


    }
```

I prefer to using the following:

```
  while(true)
  {


  }
```

Is there a way that I can customize emacs to following this format?

Thank you

Comment: hmm.. which language and which major mode.? `C` and `cc-mode` ??.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `c-set-style` and friends to change which general style of indentation you want.  You can also change individual pieces of the indentation engine to get something very personalized.  See the [EmacsWiki page](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC) for details.  What you probably want (to a first approximation) is simply

```
(c-set-style "bsd")
```

in a hook, or

```
(setq c-default-style "bsd")
```

in your `.emacs`.

Comment: I have auto-complete setting that has known conflict with above solution. This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/663636) solved my problem.